# When did PHP introduce type casting?

Tags: php, history

The [PHP website](https://php.net/) tells you which versions each function is supported in and often the version a function was first introduced in, but it doesn't do the same for older language features. When was type casting first introduced? i.e. `(int)$var` or `(string)$var`.

Comment: The [first comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#24809) about typecasting was posted 13 years ago, which gives you a hint. This also means that, unless you're just interested in PHP history, you shouldn't care about the actual answer. If the version you actually use is *that old*, you should *really* consider an upgrade.

Comment: @MainMa Some programmers have told me that `(int)$var` is a weird new feature and that `intval($var)` or `settype($var, 'int')` is much better.

Comment: @CJDennis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-casting-to-int-int-x

Comment: @CJDennis And your idea is to prove them wrong by saying that this feature is _old_?

Comment: @VincentSavard Pretty much. If this feature's been around for over 16 years and has stable and non-surprising behaviour (unlike `intval()`) why would you avoid its use?

Answer (score 5):

PHP 3.

PHP 3.0 was released in October 2000.<sup>[[1, scroll bottom]](https://secure.php.net/releases/)</sup>

Code about type casting could be found in one of the earliest php-src commits,<sup>[[2]](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/573b46022c46ab41a879c23f4ea432dd4d0c102e/Zend/zend-scanner.l#L562)</sup> which was in 1999. This proves that type casting most likely existed in PHP 3.

PHP 2 docs asked users to use `SetType()` or `IntVal()` to move the type from double to int,<sup>[[3]](http://php.net/manual/phpfi2.php#overload)</sup> which suggests that PHP 2 didn't have type casting directly.

Therefore it can be deduced that type casting was introduced in PHP 3.